# multiple nested resources for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've being following the rails getting started tutorial and have been changing the model to help my understading of rails.
I have an article model which has_many comments:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments
end
```

The view to create the comment is in a partial (as per the rails tutorial)

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>    
<% end %>
```

This works fine but I wanted to split this out a bit to make a commenter a separate model (I know its not great OO but I just experimenting here!)

I therefore created a Commenter model:

```
class Commenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

changed the Comment to :

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :commenter
  belongs_to :article
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :commenters

resources :articles do
 resources :comments
end  

resources :comments do
  resource :commenter
end
```

I'd like to create the Comment and the commenter at the same time in a single form but I'm stuck on how to change the view to achieve this as the view builds the comments model, do I also need to build the commenter model here? if so how do I achieve this?

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>    
<% end %>
```

Comment: What you are trying to implement is called **nested attributes**. They will likely be covered later in your tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

For what your looking to do, you need to implement Nested Forms.
From the code you have provided, below I have shown how I would change it.

**Models**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments    # This is required for @article to save the forms nested within it

validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :commenter    # Required to save nested Commenter form
end

class Commenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

**Article Controller**

In the action that will be called when someone decides to comment on an article, you will need to select the @article and create a comment and also a commenter for the comment. These have to be created before the form is rendered, otherwise they won't be displayed.

```
def create_comment

    @article.find(:id_of_article)                     
    @comment = @article.comments.find(:id_of_new_comment)  
    @comment.create_commenter 

end
```

**View**

Finally the form

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for(:comments, @comment) do |comment| %>  # As article will have many comments, you need to specify the new comment you want to display

        <%= comment.label :comment %><br>
        <%= comment.text_field :comment %>

        <%= comment.fields_for(:commenter) do |commenter| %>

            <%= commenter.label :commenter_name %>
            <%= commenter.text_field :commenter_name %>

        <%end%>
    <%end%>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Anyway, I hope this helps. Although if you're still doing your tutorials, you should learn this fairly soon anyway.